# Issue with Google OAuth login in React app - Works on localhost but not on domain server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-oauth, mern, vercel

I'm facing an issue with Google OAuth login in my React app. The authentication process works perfectly on localhost, but when deployed to a domain server (hosted on Vercel), the login is not successful. I have already verified the following:

1. **Google Console Configuration:**

   - The JavaScript origin and authorize URL in the Google Console are correctly set for my domain.

2 **Network Status:**

- When attempting to login using Google on the domain server, the network status shows a status 200 response.

---

Here is a snippet of the relevant code:

```
handleGoogleLogin = async (credentialResponse) => {
    var decoded = jwtDecode(credentialResponse.credential);
    const user = {
      name: decoded.name, // Customize based on Google's response
      email: decoded.email,
      sub:decoded.sub,
      

     // Customize based on Google's response
      // Add more fields as needed
    };

    try {
      // Check if the response structure matches your expectations
     
     
        // Store the user data in your MongoDB database using an API endpoint
       
        const res = await axios.post(`/api/v1/auth/google`, { user })
        console.log("res",res.data);
        console.log(res.data.token)
        if (res && res.data.success) {
          toast.success('Logged in successfully');
          setAuth({
            ...auth,
            user: res.data.user,
            token:res.data.token, // Update the user field correctly
          });
         console.log("res",auth);
          navigate(location.state || '/');
          localStorage.setItem('auth', JSON.stringify(res.data));
        } else {
          toast.error(res.data.message);
        }
    
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('eer',error);
      toast.error('Something went wrong');
    }
  }; <GoogleOAuthProvider  clientId="cliend id">
  <GoogleLogin
                    onSuccess={handleGoogleLogin}
                    rememberMe={true} 
                    onError={() => {
                      console.log('Login Failed');
                    }}
                  />
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
```

Additionally, the app is built on the MERN stack, hosted on Vercel, and environment variables in the **`.env`** file are correctly configured.

I have thoroughly checked the above aspects, and everything seems to be in order. However, the login is not working on the domain server. Any guidance or suggestions on what might be causing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: I am not using firebase.as I have already add the url and javascript origin in the gcp .it is working for local host.and even for domain server when I inspect it showing status 200 .here is the website link you can check it www.jobsea.asia .by trying login . You can check it showing 200 status when login..

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't add your domain to firebase console, you need to do so to allow authentication.

Comment: I am not using firebase.in domain server when you login using Google .in network it showing status 200.

Comment: I think this would have been better as a comment on the post perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

*Make sure that your server is configured to handle CORS properly. If there are CORS issues, they might prevent the successful completion of the OAuth flow.*

Comment: I think there is no issue with cors as it showing network status 200 .when I try login using google.but still unable to get successfully login .here is the website link : www.jobsea.asia